# Las Vergnas theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> I am supposed to prove that the graph satisfies the Las Vergnas
> theorem. Here is the graph:
>
> [image]

Las Vergnas theorem is the following:

$G$ is a graph and $V(G)=(v_1,...,v_n)$. There is no such $i,j$ such that $i<j, i+j \geq n, v_iv_j \notin E(G),
deg(v_i) \leq i, deg(v_j) \leq j-1, deg(v_i) + deg(v_j) \leq n-1$. Then $G$ is hamiltonian

But if I label the vertices like this:

[image]

I found such $i$, $j$: $i=2$ and $j=4$, so the graph does not satisfy Las Vergnas theorem.

Is there something, which I misunderstood or where is the mistake.

Thanks

Comment: @PrasunBiswas but then that is counterexample or? Because the theorem says that such numbers do not exist, but we found them

Comment: The theorem does not say that such numbers do not exist. The theorem says that *if* such numbers do not exist, then the graph is hamiltonian. Precision matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote the actual theorem (as stated in Berge's *Graphs and Hypergraphs*, on p. 208 of the 1973 edition):

> Let $G=(X,E)$ be a simple graph of order $n \ge 3$. Let the vertices $x_i$ of $G$ be indexed arbitrarily, and let $q$ be an integer, where $0 \le q \le n-1$. If $$\left.\begin{array}{l}1 \le i < j \le n \\ i+j \ge n-q \\ d_G(x_i) \le i+q \\ d_G(x_j) \le j+q-1 \\ [x_i,x_j] \notin E\end{array}\right\} \implies d_G(x_i) + d_G(x_j) \ge n+q$$ then, for each $F \subset E$ with $|F|=q$ such that the connected components of $(X,F)$ are elementary chains, there exists a hamiltonian cycle that contains $F$.

Here, we want $q=0$, so the conditions are the same as in the question; the point that I am making is that the hypotheses in the question are satisfied if there is **any** ordering of the vertices that works.

In the case of your graph, if we swap the order of vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ in your labeling, there will no longer be any pair $(i,j)$ violating the conditions, because the only two vertices in the right positions with the right degrees will be adjacent. So the graph does satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem.

*As a side note: it is incorrect to say "the graph satisfies the theorem" or "the graph does not satisfy the theorem". All graphs satisfy the theorem: it's a theorem! Some graphs don't satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem, but that's okay. The only counterexample would be a graph that did satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem, but wasn't hamiltonian: such a graph would not satisfy the theorem. Such graphs do not exist.*

Comment: Thank you so much